# Unable to enable button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some init jquery function in witch i set some attribute that i need to have when application start (for example i need to btnRun set on disable on start. This work:

Code is simple:

```
$('#btnRun').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Next thing is that on check box change i change btnRun on Enable,or disable (if checked enable,else disable);

```
$('#cbEdit').change(function () {
   var checkboxValue = $(this).is(':checked');
   if (!checkboxValue) 
   { 
      $('#div1').find('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
     //disabling all input and textarea on div1,bntRun is not on this div1           
      $('#btnRun').attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
    else 
    {
         $('#div1').find('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('disabled', false);
         document.getElementById("lblFn").focus();
         $('#btnRun').attr('disabled', false);
    }
    ...
    ...
```

What is problem, with input text,and text area this work  perfect,but whit button not always.
If I in init use that code  that i wrote on start `($('#btnRun').attr("disabled", "disabled");)`

its not working it is always disable. I think that is important that i wrote that i in Init function disabled input text and text area to.
If i remove button disabled line of code is work, but than is problem that I need on start to have disabled button and later enable it. That i do this only with button i wold understand that something other is not OK, but i cannot to find why input text and text-area work on same way, butt button don't.
`.attr` option is only that I was try, prop to,and with `.removeatrr` to, but it is not thing is this because with out init disabled it work just fine.

Comment: Or `removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: @Exception I am practically sure  that is not a problem. I wrote that i try, but i wrote that when i disabled prop, or attr way it is not work, but on check box change only work...Things that i not understand, why same in work for input text on same way(when i use line in init for disable input text in init to)

Answer (score 2):

You  shouldn't use `attr` but [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('#btnRun').prop("disabled", true);
```

or

```
$('#btnRun').prop("disabled", false);
```

From the jQuery Docs:

> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr.

Comment: I wrote on end , that i try that to... I am not the best in english ,if i not write some clear, ask :)

Comment: @Nick I see. What do you mean  "with out init disabled it work just fine"?

Comment: I have init funct in whitchi set disabled attr for btnRun and inputs... If i from that init function remove line that disable button it is work on checkbox change, but for input work when i disabled input and textare in init to

Comment: @Nick Did you tried using `prop` anywhere where you change the disable state, specially in your init function.

Comment: @Nick Is your if working as excepted? (check using alerts, or logs) Also try replacing `$(this).is(':checked');` with `$(this).prop("checked")`.  If that doesn't help please post your init function, and create a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the attribute, e.g.

```
$('#btnRun').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use prop method insted of attr for next properties:
disabled,
selected,
checked.

```
$('#btnRun').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I wrote on end , that i try that to... I am not the best in english ,if i not write some clear, ask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for text inputs, it will hardly find any buttons:

```
 find('input[type="text"] ...
```

change to

```
 find('input[type="button"]
```

Comment: OP is using an ID to select the button

Comment: Yes i need disable only one button.